# PropertyChanged method assignment

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

I've implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for a simple WPF view-viewmodel and when I call my

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

on GoodText's set like

```
this.RaisePropertyChanged("GoodText");
```

the PropertyChanged event has a method that I never assigned to it.

When it has been assigned? Who did it?

**EDIT:**

Thank you, great advices, but I think Willem's answer is what i was searching for, i mean: when I say

```
<Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding CheckButtonCommand}" />
```

It's something like (ugly pseudocode)

```
PropertyChanged += Button.GiveMeThePropertyValue;
```

?
So the binding added the handler to the PropertyChanged event?

Comment: Correct. The binding adds the handler, so it can be notified of updates, and act accordingly. It's the way MVVM binding works. The object that gets bound only needs to know about INotifyPropertyChanged to get update notifications (and/or INotifyCollectionChanged for collection updates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the property (and thus the class) is data bound in XAML (or through code).

If you bind to a class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, the UIElement that is being bound to the source class will hookup an event handler to be able to monitor property changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is the magic of "field-like events" and the magic of delegates.

Firstly field-like events: to the external caller, they look like an `event` - with `add` / `remove` accessors; they can only be used with `+=` / `-=`. However, to the declaring type they appear more like a ***field*** - so you have direct access to the delegate. Including reading and assigning the value.

As for where the method came from. That is (sort of) *what a delegate is*. That is actually `.Invoke(...)` on the delegate instance; but the `.Invoke` is implicit. That happens for any delegate, for example:

```
Action<string> action = s => Console.WriteLine(s);
// following are identical (but with different values, obviously)
action("hello");
action.Invoke("world");
```

A couple of suggestions, though:

1: there's a really tiny unlikley-to-bite-you thread race at the moment; I suggest:

```
var handler = PropertyChanged;
if(handler != null) handler(this, ...);
```

2: with recent compilers, you can avoid the literal:

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName=null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

which allows you to call it from the `GoodText` property simply as:

```
this.RaisePropertyChanged();
```

Less code = fewer things to get wrong (copy/paste names, etc)